# Testing conditional validation with controller inputs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have custom validator for password that takes a updating_password field from the controller

```
attr_accessor :updating_password

validates :password, presence: true, if: :should_validate_password?
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: :should_validate_password?

def should_validate_password?
   updating_password || new_record?
end
```

I want to stub out the updating_password field in my User model RSpec test, something like

```
before(:each) do
  @user_valid = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end

it "validates for password when updating_password is true" do
  old_password = @user_valid.password
  subject { @user_valid }
  allow(subject).to receive(:updating_password).and_return(true)
  @user_valid.update(password: "short", password_confirmation: "short")
  expect(@user_valid.password).to eql(old_password)
end
```

The password should not be updated in this case because it is too short but the test is failing. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not stubbing out your model validations. Instead you might test what you're trying to do like this

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb
describe User do
  describe 'validations' do
    context 'while updating password' do
      let(:user){ FactoryGirl.create(:user, updating_password: true) }

      it 'requires password to be at least 6 characters long' do
        expect {user.update!(password: 'short')}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord:RecordInvalid)
      end

      it 'requires password to be present' do
        expect {user.update!(password: nil))}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord:RecordInvalid)
      end
    end
  end
end
```